# How to push react elements into an array using back ticks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to push icons into an array by grabbing the name from data and simply adding: "<" and "/>" so that it becomes an Mui Icon.

I've renamed the imported icons to match the names in data but when I push them into my render array, all it renders is strings.

Any ideas?

```js
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addReaction } from "../features/postsSlice";

import ThumbsUp from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbUp";
import Happy from "@mui/icons-material/SentimentSatisfiedAlt";
import Sad from "@mui/icons-material/SentimentVeryDissatisfied";
import Heart from "@mui/icons-material/Favorite";
import Coffee from "@mui/icons-material/LocalCafe";
import { IconButton } from "@mui/material";

const Reactions = () => {
  const reactions = useSelector((state) =>
    Object.keys(state.posts[1].reactions)
  );
  const emojis = [];
  reactions.map((reaction) => {
    const capitalize = reaction[0].toUpperCase() + reaction.slice(1);
    emojis.push(<IconButton>{`<${capitalize} />`}</IconButton>);
  });
  console.log(emojis);
  return emojis;
};

export default Reactions;
```

Comment: Small note: if you're using `map` you don't need to `push`. _`map` returns a new array_

Comment: Do you try to use `Reactions` as a component? I mean in code you use it like `<Reactions />`?

Comment: @RukkiesMan yea in my code I'm using Reactions as a component

Comment: Components need one root element so if you wrap emojis in `<>{ emojis }</>` it will work

Comment: Furthermore I agree with @andy that you can better use map like this `const emojis = reactions.map(reaction => { const capitalize = reaction[0].toUpperCase() + reaction.slice(1); return (<IconButton>{`<${capitalize} />`}</IconButton>); });

Comment: I tried wrapping the array in fragments, strings are still displayed

Comment: Why don't you just bind the JSX element to the reactions so basically give it values like `const reactions = [<SmileyFace />, <SadFace />];` in practise JSX elements are Objects after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use this way:

```js
emojis.push(<IconButton>{`<${capitalize} />`}</IconButton>);
```

Instead what you can do is have an object map for all those:

```js
// Create an object with all the possible elements you would use.
const MyMap = {
  ThumbsUp,
  Happy,
  Sad,
  Heart,
  Coffee
};

// And use it this way:
const EmojiElem = MyMap[capitalize];
emojis.push(<IconButton><EmojiElem /></IconButton>);
```

Comment: @ether Thanks, this is exactly I did in my app, and it worked, that's why shared it. It's always good to use the options, the new JavaScript provides like dynamic indexing and implicit values in objects (not sure the exact name).

Comment: Is there anyway to turn the keys from data into an object so you don't have to manually create the object yourself?

Comment: @ether Great question, you can also do a `import * as MyMap from "@mui/icons-material"` but the library doesn't seem to support it, I just tried with version 5.11.11! 

Comment: Haha nice try, unfortunate it's not supported

Comment: Sorry man, limitation of the library. However you can have one single dedicated file to import and export this way to reduce the clutter, but that will be a manual process! 